# Using SQL script on data views for calculating stats

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

I have created an autoamtion that pulls the data from Data View and saved the records in a data extension (My_Sub_DE) using the following sql query.

```
SELECT *
FROM ent._Subscribers WITH (NOLOCK)
```

Now, that I have all records in the data extension (My_Sub_DE), I am using the following SQL query to pull top 10 domain names and saving it in another data extension (My_Sub_DE_DomainsStats)

```
select top 10 Domain, count(*) AS Count
from My_Sub_DE
group by Domain
order by Count desc
```

**My data extension - My_Sub_DE_DomainsStats, includes these 3 columns**
- Domain
- Count
- Percent

Currently, I am getting the top 10 domains with count based on my above (2nd) sql query but I want to calculate the percentage also.

Can anyone please help with the SQL query?

This is what I have created so far but I am getting error - ***Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Percent'.***

```
select top 10 Domain, count(*) AS Count, (count(*)*100 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ent._Subscribers WITH (NOLOCK))) AS Percent
from My_Sub_DE
group by Domain
order by Count desc
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that 'percent' is a SQL function, so it is causing validation issues.  Simplest solution is to name it something else - e.g. (ofTotal) and it should work fine.

Comment: A new issue that I am facing is that, the calculated ofTotal...if any ofTotal is less than 1%, it is coming as 0 in my data extension (My_Sub_DE_DomainsStats) and in addition to that I see the calculated percent in even numbers only, nothing is showing up as decimal value. The ofTotal data type is already set as Decimal 18,3. Any advice?

Comment: I would use: CONVERT(decimal(5,2),(CONVERT(float,count(*))/CONVERT(float,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ent._Subscribers))*100)) AS ofTotal

Comment: I am not sure if you forgot * with count so I added in my query but getting error - `The query syntax is invalid Incorrect syntax near '?'.`

Comment: the comments seemed to have removed some of my formatting.  I will try again `CONVERT(decimal(5,2),(CONVERT(float,count(*))/CONVERT(float,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM _Subscribers))*100)) + '%' AS ofTotal`

Comment: Still getting the same error - `The query syntax is invalid
Incorrect syntax near '?'.` It is strange because there is no "?" in the query. Just curious. would you like me to keep data datatype of ofTotal as Text or something else?

Comment: text would be recommended as you are adding in a '.' with decimal and the % at the end.   I have run the query on my account and I have had no issues, so it might be another part of your SQL that potentially is breaking

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59249/discussion-between-l-k-and-gortonington).

Comment: Ok so I tested the query provided by you and I get the error `Overwrite Data Action Selected. This action will overwrite all of the current data in the target data extension`. But I would like to overwrite the data so fresh data is always there. I never faced this issue before with any other queries, why this particular query?

Comment: JUST FYI...I do not have any primary key set on the data extension where I am saving this data via query. Do I need one?

Comment: You don't need primary key - the Overwrite statement should be a warning and not an error. should be able to select OK and save it and run it.